# elasticsearch scoring on multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

i have an index for any quarter of a year ("index-2015.1","index-2015.2"... )

i have around 30 million documents on each index.

a document has a text field ('title')

my document sorting method is (1)_score  (2)created date

the problem is:

when searching for some text on on 'title' field for all indexes ("index-201*"), always the first results is from one index.

lets say if i am searching for 'title=home' and i have 10k documents on "index-2015.1" with title=home and 10k documents on "index-2015.2" with title=home then the first results are all documents from "index-2015.1" (and not from "index-2015.2", or mixed) even that on "index-2015.2" there are documents with "created date" higher then in "index-2015.1".

is there a reason for this?

Comment: Do the `_score`s match with the order?

Comment: dont understand the question. can you explain? thanks

Comment: The order you get for documents is the correct one? (based on _score and then created date)

Comment: only correct by _score. (by created date its ordered within the index). the problem that its ordered by indexes (first index first, and on...)

Comment: If it's correct by `_score` then this is how it should be. You ordered by `_score`.

Comment: Change the order of your sorting rules: (1)created date, (2)_score. Also, if you want to favor one index over another you can use [indices boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-index-boost.html).

Comment: i am now understands that _scoring in each index is different. so this is the reason. but can i set the scoring for all indexes. i mean that elastic will calculate the score according to all indexes? or there is other option? i want to get the most relevant docs for 'title:home' from all indexes sorted by created date..

Comment: Then change the order of your sorting rules: (1)created date, (2)_score and, alternatively, as I mentioned maybe you can use [indices boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-index-boost.html) (it depends on your requirements).

Comment: indices boost will be probebly the answer. order by (1)created date, (2)_score wont give me a good solution because if i get 'home' in March and 'xxxxxxxx home' in April so i get first the 'xxxxxxxx home' even that 'home' is more relevant

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is probably, that the scores are specific to the index. So if you really have multiple indices, the result score of the documents will be calculated (slightly) different for each index.

Simply put, among other things, the score of a matching document is dependent on the query terms and their occurrences in the index. The score is calculated in regard to the index (actually, by default even to each separate shard). There are some normalizations elasticsearch does, but I don't know the details of those.

I'm not really able to explain it well, but here's the article about scoring. I think you want to read at least the part about TF/IDF. Which I think, should explain why you get different scores.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

---

EDIT:

So, after testing it a bit on my machine, it seems possible to use another search_type, to achieve a score suitable for your case.

```
POST /index1,index2/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
    "query" : {
       "match": {
          "title": "home"
       }
    }
}
```

The important part is **search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch**. If you are programming java or something similar, there should be a way to specify it in the request. For details about the search_types, refer to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html).

Basically it will first collect the term-frequencies on all affected shards (+ indexes). Therefore the score should be generalized over all these.

Comment: i see, so what can you recomend me to do in order to get the document with the highest score but with a newer created date?

Comment: What I know, dfs_query_then_fetch collect all term frequencies  on all shards. But do on indexes too? Shards are Index specific

Answer (score 2):

according to  Andrei Stefan and Slomo,  index boosting solve my problem:

```
   body={ 
       "indices_boost" : { "index-2015.4" : 1.4, "index-2015.3" : 1.3,"index-2015.2" : 1.2 ,"index-2015.1" : 1.1 }
        }
```

EDIT:

using search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch (as Slomo described) will solve the problem in better way (depend what is your business model...)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time this weekend. How are you able to determine the boost factor? Isn't this quite `random`? I think what you really need is to specify another search_type. I'll edit my answer.