# How to use elasticsearch indexes with different weight

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created more elasticsearch indexes for different type of information in our system. Mainly they are used individually to look for elements in a particular index. However we have a general search on our home page, where the user can search in all indexes. E.g. the following search will be used:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my-index-%2A/_doc/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{                         
  "size":25,              
  "query":{               
    "bool":{              
      "must":[            
        {                 
          "term":{"languageCode":"de"}
        },                
        {                 
          "bool":{        
            "should":[
              {
                "simple_query_string":{
                  "query":"search-term",
                  "fields":[
                    "title_*.language^50",
                    "description_*.language^10",
                    "content_*.language^1"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

I'm using in this search many indexes with wildcard (`my-index-*/_doc/_search`). It works absolutely correct, but my problem is, that I want that one of the indexes generates less score as the others. Is there any possibility to give less weight to an index in a multi-index query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed apply an [index boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-index-boost)

```
GET /_search
{
    "indices_boost" : [
        { "my-index-do-not-want" : 0.5 }
    ]
}
```

In addition, depending on your use case you might want to consider turning on `dfs_query_then_fetch` for that query, as mentioned [here].([elasticsearch scoring on multiple indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432639/elasticsearch-scoring-on-multiple-indexes))
That way, your scores should be more comparable between indexes.